# How to represent Map<String, Map<String, Obj>> in String format

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have following code and I want to give user output in given format which is easy to read.

How to achieve this using Lambda. I tried map function but not able to get the result.

Following is the output that I am expecting:

```
ID1=DEFAULT1 => NewYork

ID1=DEFAULT2 => London

ID1=DEFAULT3 => India


ID2=DEFAULT1 => NewYork

ID2=DEFAULT2 => London

ID2=DEFAULT3 => India
```

---

```
public class Test{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Map<String, TimePeriod>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Time>>();

        Map<String,TimePeriod> timePeriodMap = new HashMap<>();

        timePeriodMap.put("DEFAULT1",new TimePeriod("NewYork"));
        timePeriodMap.put("DEFAULT2",new TimePeriod("London"));
        timePeriodMap.put("DEFAULT3",new TimePeriod("India"));

        Map<String,Map<String,TimePeriod>> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
        stringMap.put("ID1",timePeriodMap);
        stringMap.put("ID2",timePeriodMap);


    }
}
    class TimePeriod {

        String zone;

        public TimePeriod(String zone) {
            this.zone = zone;
        }

        public String getZone() {
            return zone;
        }

        public void setZone(String zone) {
            this.zone = zone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) Do you want to just to print out the result or map to a specific data structure?

Comment: 2) What is your attempt so far?

Comment: @Nikolas I tried following but not able to complete :       stringMap.entrySet().stream().map(
                                mapEntry ->
                                        mapEntry.getValue().entrySet().stream().map(
                                                timePeriodEntry -> mapEntry.getKey() + "=" + timePeriodEntry.getKey() + timePeriodEntry.getRegion()
                                        ).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
                        ).map(s -> s)).get().toString();

Comment: I only need it in string so that I can print to user

Comment: Well, you only need to read these values and make a printable output as a String. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for use [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) because this shall be achieved fairly easily with a simple procedural for-each approach. Use [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) to make a printable output and [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) to keep the keys ordered.

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());

stringMap.forEach((id, timeMap) -> {
    timeMap.forEach((defaultValue, timePeriod) -> {
         joiner.add(String.format("%s=%s => %s", id, defaultValue, timePeriod.getZone()));
    });
});

System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

Result:

```
ID1=DEFAULT1 => NewYork
ID1=DEFAULT2 => London
ID1=DEFAULT3 => India
ID2=DEFAULT1 => NewYork
ID2=DEFAULT2 => London
ID2=DEFAULT3 => India
```

Comment: Yes, the class `StringJoiner` overrides `toString` method, however, I prefer to show how to request the `String` type which might be useful in later processing :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Maps types look a bit wrong.

Did you mean to declare `Map<String, Map<String, TimePeriod>> map`?

If so, you don't need that second stringMap. You can add the timePeriod entries to the map variable.

If just looking to print, you can do this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, TimePeriod>> map = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String,TimePeriod> timePeriodMap = new HashMap<>();

    timePeriodMap.put("DEFAULT1",new TimePeriod("NewYork"));
    timePeriodMap.put("DEFAULT2",new TimePeriod("London"));
    timePeriodMap.put("DEFAULT3",new TimePeriod("India"));

    map.put("ID1",timePeriodMap);
    map.put("ID2",timePeriodMap);


    map.forEach((id, timePeriods) -> {
        timePeriods.forEach((defaultValue, timePeriod) -> System.out.println(id + "=" + defaultValue + " => " + timePeriod.getZone()));
    });
```

The Map interface has a forEach method allowing you to iterate the entrySet.
By iterating the 'outer' entryset of map and then iterating the 'inner' entryset of the nested map you can get the desired output.

Comment: Edited it. I need string in return  as I will display it on GUI

Comment: See @Nikolas answer for a good way to add the output to a variable. You could also replace both "new HashMap<>()" with "new LinkedHashMap<>()"

Comment: There are three maps declared in OPs answer. Yes you could also use printf.